R function for averaging observations across sources stored in identical table formats
I was wondering if there is a method in R for the following scenario:
I have collected data from various weather stations in the area. In order to do my analysis, I want to combine the values from each station to create the average picture for the area. All of the data is in the exact same format (example below) so I would want to keep the Day/Month/Year the same while averaging the individual cells in the other columns.



Day
Month
Year
Min Temp
Max Temp
Mean Temp
Humidity




1
1
2023
1
15
8
98


2
1
2023
-2
9
3.5
82



The only solutions I can think of are more manual - adding the columns and then creating an average but this does not seem practical if I increase the types of observations (and therefore increase the number of columns significantly) and have even more sources and therefore dozens of tables.
I appreciate any advice on this!

Assuming you have station data stored in a directory in .csv format with filenames like "station01_weather_data_2023.csv", you can do
> ## store individual paths
> fns <- list.files('/path/to/dir/', pattern='^station', full.names=TRUE)
> ## read the .CSVs
> weather_data <- lapply(setNames(fns, sub('.csv', '', basename(fns))), read.csv)
> ## process data 
> Map(`[<-`, weather_data, 'station', value=names(weather_data)) |>  ## add station variable
+   lapply(\(x) cbind(Date=ISOdate(x$Year, x$Month, x$Day, 0), x[-(1:3)])) |>  ## make POSIX date
+   do.call(what='rbind') |>  ## rbind
+   aggregate(cbind(Min.Temp, Max.Temp, Mean.Temp, Humidity) ~ Date, mean)  ## calc. averages
        Date  Min.Temp  Max.Temp Mean.Temp Humidity
1 2023-01-01  1.000000 15.000000  8.166667 98.00000
2 2023-01-02 -1.833333  9.000000  4.133333 80.66667
3 2023-01-03 -3.000000  8.666667  3.666667 82.66667

Note, that aggregate(na.action=na.omit) is default, so missing values are removed to still get the mean. If you don't want that behavior and prefer NA if there's any NA for specific time point in any station, set aggregate(., na.action=na.pass).

CSV Data:
station01_weather_data_2023.csv
"Day","Month","Year","Min Temp","Max Temp","Mean Temp","Humidity"
1,1,2023,1,15,8,98
2,1,2023,-2,NA,3.5,82
3,1,2023,-3,8,3,81

station02_weather_data_2023.csv
"Day","Month","Year","Min Temp","Max Temp","Mean Temp","Humidity"
1,1,2023,0,14,7.5,97
2,1,2023,-2.5,8,3.9,81
3,1,2023,-4,9,4,86

station03_weather_data_2023.csv
"Day","Month","Year","Min Temp","Max Temp","Mean Temp","Humidity"
1,1,2023,2,16,9,99
2,1,2023,-1,10,5,79
3,1,2023,-2,9,4,81


This worked great - thanks for your help!
